# Outlook prompts for password when connect to Exchange via HTTP is enabled

Tags: exchange-2010, iis-7.5, outlook, windows-sbs-2011, outlook-anywhere

We have an SBS 2011 server running Exchange 2010 SP3 and two domain-joined Terminal Servers running Outlook 2010 & 2013.

When any Exchange account is configured to *Connect to Microsoft Exchange using HTTP* (the default for all users) Outlook prompts for a username and password. Everything works when you provide valid credentials. If *Connect to Microsoft Exchange using HTTP* is turned off Outlook connects without prompting for credentials.

Also, Outlook Anywhere does not work outside of our local network. Outlook Web Access (OWA) works fine from inside and outside the network. We have also confirmed RPC Client access is working.

I have a feeling there is an issue in IIS, but I'm not sure.

Our orginisation is a too large to go to each user and turn off *Connect to Microsoft Exchange using HTTP*.

Does does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you using the default self-signed security certificate for Exchange 2010, or did you configure your SBS 2011 server with a public SSL certificate?  If the latter, is it a single name certificate or a SAN/UCC certificate?

Answer (score 0):

A password cache corruption can cause the error. On the server change the exchange RPC client access service from network service to local account and then change it back again.

Comment: Thanks! but sadly this did not work.